# Incorrect syntax near 'for' SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, keyword

I want to add a new Column to an existing Table that has already Data in it. 
The Column should be NOT NULL. 
Because of that i want to set a Default Value. But when i do it throws the following exception:
"Incorrect syntax near 'for'"

```
ALTER TABLE Semester ADD SIDNew uniqueidentifier NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT DF_SIDNew DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' FOR SIDNew
```

I already had a look at [How to set a default value for an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)
and [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477134/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-for) but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply lose the part `FOR SIDNew`. You are adding a new column with a default constraint. You are not adding a new default constraint to an existing column.

Answer (score 3):

The `FOR` keyword is only required if you're adding default values to Azure SQL Data Warehouse or Parallel Data Warehouse. If you're using normal relational SQL Server (on-premise or Azure) then you can just write it without the FOR

```
ALTER TABLE Semester ADD SIDNew uniqueidentifier NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT DF_SIDNew DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx